# Coloring a coordination of 2 Dimensions Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to make a really simple Maze game , which is a predefined 2 Dimensions array in a C# console application. Player uses arrow keys to move . The player spawns at [0,0] coordination which is colored red while the rest are white.
whenever player uses arrow keys to move , the new coordination's color changes to red. I'm wondering how can I change the color of a string which is set in a specific coordination of a 2 Dimensions array (the array is defined as a string).
I'd be glad if you help.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stack MyStack = new Stack();
        string[,] arr = new string[5, 5] { { "1", "0", "0", "0", "0" }, { "1", "0", "0", "0", "0" }, { "1", "0", "0", "0", "0" }, { "1", "1", "0", "0", "0" }, {"1", "1", "1", "1", "1" }};

        var rowCount = arr.GetLength(0);
        var colCount = arr.GetLength(1);
        for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < colCount; col++)
                Console.Write(String.Format("{0}\t", arr[row, col]));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Are you talking about the background color of the console in that coordinate?

Comment: No actually the text color

Comment: Your first step is to figure out how to color the text in the first place. Then, you need to come up with an interactive display technique; your code above isn't going to work for that. Then you need to track in your array for display the color to display. There are a variety of ways to do this, but the simplest and most effective IMHO is to store in the array your user-defined type that keeps that information and the character to display. Your question as asked is way too broad; there's not a single line of code here that would eventually be found in a good solution.

Comment: my advice is to use a set of function that take a coordinate, a character and a color (or two for fore- and background) and to put out the grid cell by cell.

Comment: Use `ForegroundColor` and `BackgroundColor` of the `Console` to play with colors. `Console.ResetColor()` will set it back to default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution. You can modify it all you want.

```
using System;

struct Index
{
    public int i;
    public int j;
}
public class Node
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public ConsoleColor Color { get; set; }
    public Node(int value, ConsoleColor color = ConsoleColor.White)
    {
        Value = value;
        Color = color;
    }
}
public class Maze
{
    private readonly int _size;
    private Node[,] _maze;
    private Index _currentIndex;

    public Maze(int size)
    {
        _size = size;
        _maze = new Node[_size, _size];
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        int k = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < _size; j++)
                _maze[i, j] = new Node(k++);
        _maze[0, 0].Color = ConsoleColor.Red;
    }

    private void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Use the direction keys to move starting at (0,0). I'll not move until you enter a valid direction.\nYou can only move within the maze.\nYou cannot move to a red spot.\n\nPress ESC to quit.\n\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < _size; j++)
            {
                Node node = _maze[i, j];
                Console.ForegroundColor = node.Color;
                Console.Write(string.Format("{0:00}",node.Value));
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    public void Run()
    {        
        Initialize();
        Print();
        ConsoleKey key;
        do
        {
            key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
            ValidateMove(key);
            Console.Clear();
            Print();
        } while (key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
    }


    private void ValidateMove(ConsoleKey key)
    {
        Index tmp = _currentIndex;
        switch (key)
        {
             case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                --tmp.i;
                if(Validate(tmp))
                {
                    _maze[tmp.i, tmp.j].Color = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    _currentIndex = tmp;
                }
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                ++tmp.i;
                if (Validate(tmp))
                {
                    _maze[tmp.i, tmp.j].Color = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    _currentIndex = tmp;
                }
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                --tmp.j;
                if (Validate(tmp))
                {
                    _maze[tmp.i, tmp.j].Color = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    _currentIndex = tmp;
                }
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                ++tmp.j;
                if (Validate(tmp))
                {
                    _maze[tmp.i, tmp.j].Color = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    _currentIndex = tmp;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private bool Validate(Index index) => (index.i < _size && index.i >= 0 && index.j < _size && index.j >= 0 && _maze[index.i, index.j].Color != ConsoleColor.Red);

    public static void Main()
    {
        Maze maze = new Maze(5);
        maze.Run();
    }
}
```